# Effect of row augmentation on value of determinant.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

[image]

Part(a) is done.
How to proceed for part (b).

My first question is what do they mean by row augmentation ?

Do they mean the row operation of adding k times the first row to third by row augmentation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I have solved my question.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

An idea: The row augmentation on $\;A\;$ is then the same as the product $\;GA\;$. Now, why not using the all important theorem that for any two square matrices $\;X,Y\;$ of the same order we have that $\;\det(XY)=\det X\cdot\det Y\;$ ?

Comment: Do they mean the row operation of adding k times the first row to third by row augmentation ?

Comment: @Member Yes, I think that's what they mean as multiplying a matrix on the left by that matrix $\;G\;$ of yours is exactly what happens, as you can easily check by yourself.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here are three relevant rules determinant manipulation:

Let $A$ be a square matrix. Let $B$ be made from $A$ by

$(1)$ Multiplication of a row of $A$ with a scalar $c$; *then $\det B = c\det A$.* 

$(2)$ Swapping two rows; *then $\det B = -\det A$.*

$(3)$ Adding a multiplum of a row to another row; *then $\det B = \det A$.*

Which one is relevant for you?